# How do I get the rotation of degree with getBoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript, css

In my game, you can click on the orange box (it's supposed to represent a monster). Upon clicking, a green line will be appended to the characters div.  For example for a better explanation:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/537c8acb9881a3bfaa6f19259de37618.gif]

This is the code I'm using to generate the line:

```
l = document.createElement('div');
l.innerHTML='<div id="oLineBar" style="  transform: rotate(' + RANDOM + 'deg);" class="fadeIn2"><div id="lineBar" class="lineBarCharacter"></div></div>';
character.appendChild(l);
```

And the CSS for that is:

```
.lineBarCharacter{
    height: 321px;
    width: 2px;
    background: rgba(39, 182, 0, 0.46)
}

#oLineBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 37px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform 1s linear;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform-style: preserve-3D;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity, -ms-transform;
}
```

Now, I'm getting that orange boxes getboundingClientRect here:

```
ClientRect {height: 95, width: 88, left: 1250.5, bottom: 471, right: 1338.5…}bottom: 471height: 95left: 1250.5right: 1338.5top: 376width: 88
```

How do I determine the correct rotational degree, **based upon where that orange box is located at** (from the getboundingClientRect data)?

Not just that specific orange box, but any data that is retrieved from getBoundingClientRect. If that makes sense.. I'm a bit lost, sorry in advance if this is confusing. I pretty much want that line to go into the same direction as where that orange box is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a math question rather than programming, but you should basically calculate the x and y differences between your character and its target, and then calculate the angle.

Assuming `x1,y1` are the character coordinates, and `x2,y2` are the target coordinates:

- `(x2-x1)` will give the x difference,
- `(y2-y1)` will give the y difference,
- `ArcTangent ( (y2-y1) / (x2-x1))` will give you the angle in radians.
- `angleInRadians * (180/pi)` will give you the angle in degrees.
- `4*ArcTangent(1)` will give you `pi`

Now in JavaScript:

```
var angle = Math.round(Math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * (180 / (4 * Math.atan(1))));
```

- Or as Maurice suggested, use `Math.atan2`:

  ```
  var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(y2 - y1 , x2 - x1) * (180 / (4 * Math.atan(1))));
  ```

**Here is an example:**

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on("mousemove", function (ev) {
        var x1 = 200,
            y1 = 200;
        var x2 = ev.clientX,
            y2 = ev.clientY;
        var d =  Math.sqrt(Math.pow((y2 - y1),2)+Math.pow((x2 - x1),2));
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2((y2 - y1) , (x2 - x1)) * (180 / (4 * Math.atan(1))));
        console.log(angle);
        $("#line").css({
            "transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)",
            "width":d+"px"
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#line {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:200px;
    width:200px;
    height:5px;
    background:green;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Here is a <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/wkz9pLse/)**</kbd> if you are on mobile.

Comment: I'd rather use Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1) to have the full 2*pi (360°) range

Comment: Hey Banana, thank you for this. Much appreciated.  I have an issue though, can you please check if I am doing everything correct? Here is what I have so far. http://i.gyazo.com/aae0d36568747f05bc279e132422e8b6.png

So the top is the character, and bottom rect data is the orange box. Here is the code: 
http://pastebin.com/kGDhFRKM

But I am getting a degree of 43. 
http://i.gyazo.com/5764d3f6d43c390938fe19d1398a6249.png

Any idea? I think my coordinates are wrong.

I'm not using the clientX, clientY event like you are, I'm using the other orange boxes Rect(), is that the problem?

Comment: @NiCkNewman can you reproduce the issue in a basic fiddle so i can see it? from your picture it looks like all you need is to apply a minus. also try using the Math.atan2 version that maurice suggested. also note that clientX's and clientY's axis center is located at top-left of the document. yours probably is located elsewhere

Comment: @Banana It was my fault, I had faulty CSS code.  It's working as intended: http://i.gyazo.com/ad3acbfc4c8d3005e777e1192b7d2262.png

The only issue is when I move my character pass the box, the line doesn't resort around an axle anymore with your code. (The middle of my character is what my CSS code was, and had it as an axle). Right? Not sure, but I'll try to figure this baby out, this is fun lol. Appreciate your math knowledge thus far!

For example: http://i.gyazo.com/3e46e3e0c26f78760606d172b4016c6a.png  It shoots off to the bottom once I pass the 180 degree mark I believe.

Comment: Awesome. Im on mobile now, when i get back to a pc ill change the example for 360deg

Comment: @Banana Yep, `var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(y2 - y1 , x2 - x1) * (180 / (4 * Math.atan(1))));` is working full 360, and this is great news. I am extremely happy. I can do so much more stuff now with the UI and character combat, ui stuff, etc now knowing that I can get the degree rotation from clientRect. You guys have been more than helpful and I truly am appreciated. I can do so much more with this, the possibilities are endless now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70391/discussion-between-nick-newman-and-banana). (I accidentally pressed this, my bad lol) But yeah, thank you!

Comment: glad we could help :)